# Toggling DrawingMode with Single Button

Tags: jquery, fabricjs

I currently have two buttons, one that enables DrawingMode and another that disables it. What I want to do is have 1 button that changes the displayed icon and function when I click it.

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  isDrawingMode: true
});

$("#select").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
});
$("#draw").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
});

$(".button").click(function() {
  $(".button span").html($(".button span").html() == '<i id="draw" class="material-icons">open_with</i>' ? '<i id="select" class="material-icons">create</i>' : '<i id="draw" class="material-icons">open_with</i>');
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<button class="button" value="True"><span><i id="select" class="material-icons">create</i></span></button>
<canvas id="canvas" height="400px" width="400px"></canvas>
```

I've tried with the code above but am lost on how to get it to toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the text content of icon using [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  isDrawingMode: false
});

$("#drawButton").click(function() {
  canvas.isDrawingMode = !canvas.isDrawingMode;
  var val = canvas.isDrawingMode ? 'open_with' : 'create';
  $("#select").text(val);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<button class="button" id='drawButton' value="True"><span><i id="select" class="material-icons">create</i></span></button>
<canvas id="canvas" height="400px" width="400px"></canvas>
```